# DynamoDbException: No Hash Key specified in schema. All Dynamo DB tables must have exactly one hash key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

It is possible with DynamoDB to create a global secondary index only with a RANGE key without a HASH key? If yes, how?

If no, can I update an item attribute that is used in a global secondary index HASH key?

**Background:** I have only 100 - 1000 items in the table. In an extremely worst case about 100 thousand entries.

A workaround is to save a dummy value with a fix value which I can use as HASH key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tables and Global Secondary Indexes need a HASH-Key, it's not optional.

You can update the hash key value **for GSIs**, changes are asynchronously replicated into the Global Secondary index. That's why you can only perform eventually consistent reads on it.